# Script that it is not effective when inserting a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a script in Google Spreadsheet, I manage to make a script to sort automatically my spreadsheet:

```
function onEdit(event){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var tableRange = "A2:G100";

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == 1,2){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( [1,2] );
      }
    }
```

My issue is that I need the script to NOT function when I insert a new row. I want people to be able to insert a row and that the sheet sort only when we edit the column 1 or 2.

Is that possible?

If not, maybe there is something to activate the event every 2 or 3 minutes. It's really not the best, but, if there is really nothing else, I might live with that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**I would rewrite this:**
I wasn't sure about the following code so I tested it and it doesn't work for me.

```
if(editedCell.getColumn()==1,2)
{   
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( [1,2] );
}
```

**Like this:**

```
var ecol=editedCell.getColumn();
if(ecol==1 || ecol==2)
{   
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( [{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
}
```

> You might wish to try the installable onChange event because you can use the e.changeType parameter `if(e.changeType=='EDIT')` to specify which changes you wish to allow.  [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)